# Finding the area of non-standard polygons missing measurements

Tags: geometry, polygons

How do you find the area of non-standard polygons missing a few measurements?
Here's a replica of a polygon i had to find the area of on my 9th grade final exam.

[image]

I understand the fact you have to turn this mess into a bunch of known shapes then find out the area of each of them.

The problem is, how am i supposed to find the missing width or height of the sides colored in red on the drawing below if it doesn't even look like anything i already have the measurements of?

[image]

Comment: With the current diagram, I think area is not determined. The diagram is imperfect, the $7$ looks the same length as the $9$. I imagine we are supposed to assume that angles that look like right angles are right angles, and maybe that angles that look like $45^\circ$ are. But there is still not quite enough.

Comment: Is that the actual question, or are you going from memory?

Comment: @John it's an exact replica of the question, i took a picture of the problem with my phone.

Comment: @user123399 There are imperfections, as Andre Nicolas said. Moreover, I do not see how that one bulge inside in the left side, is deteremined? If the lengths are not given, area will be a variable. Maybe you are missing some criteria given in the text?